# jquery serialize add additional data

Tags: jquery

I use serialize to submit forms seperate within a jquery tab. The POST data is passed fine, but i want to add some additional pre defined data, is there a way to add some somewhere behind the data: or somewhere else?

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:this.id+".php",
    cache: false,                   
    data: $("#"+this.id).serialize(),
    success:function(data){
        wijziging_nog_bevestigen = 0;
        $(innertab).html(data);
    }       
});
```

Comment: Add a hidden input field is the easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `serializeArray`

```
var data = $('#myFormName').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'myParamName', value: 'MyParamValue'});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass like,

```
 data: $("#"+this.id).serialize()+ '&var1='+var1value},
```

Answer (score 0):

at line:

```
data: $("#"+this.id).serialize(),
```

add:

```
data: $("#"+this.id).serialize() + '&' + name=value, //and so on
```